# Apache Force SSL, cannot display subfolder

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I am not an Apache expert, so I hope that someone can explain to me why when the Force SSL connection is enabled, I cannot access the Dokuwiki app / subfolder.

with FORCE SSL enabled

```
https://locahost/dokuwiki/doku.php returns 404 NOT FOUND
https://locahost returns 200 OK
```

FORCE SSL not enabled

```
http://localhost/dokuwiki/doku.php 200 OK 
http://localhost/ 200 OK
```

more /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-ssl.conf

```
        LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
        SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
        Listen 8081
        AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
        AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
        SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
        SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
        SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
        SSLMutex  "file:/usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_mutex"
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            SSLRequire %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/
        </Directory>
        <VirtualHost _default_:8081>
        DocumentRoot "/share/Web"
        ErrorLog /dev/null
        TransferLog /dev/null
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!SSLv2:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem"
        #SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/config/apache/server.key"
        #SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/config/apache/server-ca.crt"
        #SSLCACertificatePath "/etc/config/apache/ssl.crt"
        #SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/config/apache/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"
        #SSLCARevocationPath "/etc/config/apache/ssl.crl"
        #SSLCARevocationFile "/etc/config/apache/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
                 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

                    </VirtualHost>
```

more /etc/config/apache/apache.conf

```
#ServerType standalone
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache"
LockFile /var/lock/apache.lock
PidFile /var/lock/apache.pid
#ScoreBoardFile /usr/local/apache/logs/apache.scoreboard
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
MinSpareServers 2
MaxSpareServers 5
StartServers 2
MaxClients 10
MaxRequestsPerChild 30
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
Listen 80
User httpdusr
Group administrators
ServerAdmin admin@NAS
#ServerName NAS
TraceEnable off
ServerTokens Prod
DocumentRoot "/share/Web"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/share/Web">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
</IfModule>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
UseCanonicalName on
HostnameLookups Off
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
DefaultType text/plain
ErrorLog /dev/null          
#                           
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.             
#
LogLevel crit
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
        LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
        LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
</IfModule>
ServerSignature On
#
# Aliases: Add here as many aliases as you need (with no limit). The format is 
# Alias fakename realname
#
<IfModule alias_module>
        Alias /v3_menu/ "/home/httpd/v3_menu/"
        <Directory "/home/httpd/v3_menu">
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
<IfModule autoindex_module>
        AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
        AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
        AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
        AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
        AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
        AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
        AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
        AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
        AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
        AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
        AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
        AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
        AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
        AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
        AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
        AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
        AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
        AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
        AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
        AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
        AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
        AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
        AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
        AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
        DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
        ReadmeName README.html
        HeaderName HEADER.html
        IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
</IfModule>
#
# Document types.
#
<IfModule mime_module>
        TypesConfig /etc/config/apache/mime.types
        AddLanguage da .dk
        AddLanguage nl .nl
        AddLanguage en .en
        AddLanguage et .ee
        AddLanguage fr .fr
        AddLanguage de .de
        AddLanguage el .el
        AddLanguage he .he
        AddCharset ISO-8859-8 .iso8859-8
        AddLanguage it .it
        AddLanguage ja .ja
        AddCharset ISO-2022-JP .jis
        AddLanguage kr .kr
        AddCharset ISO-2022-KR .iso-kr
        AddLanguage nn .nn
        AddLanguage no .no
        AddLanguage pl .po
        AddCharset ISO-8859-2 .iso-pl
        AddLanguage pt .pt
        AddLanguage pt-br .pt-br
        AddLanguage ltz .lu
        AddLanguage ca .ca
        AddLanguage es .es
        AddLanguage sv .sv
        AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
        AddLanguage ru .ru
        AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
        AddCharset Big5              .Big5      .big5
        AddCharset WINDOWS-1251 .cp-1251
        AddCharset CP866                .cp866
        AddCharset ISO-8859-5   .iso-ru
        AddCharset KOI8-R          .koi8-r
        AddCharset UCS-2                .ucs2
        AddCharset UCS-4                .ucs4
        AddCharset UTF-8                .utf8
        <IfModule negotiation_module>
                LanguagePriority en da nl et fr de el it ja kr no pl pt pt-br ru ltz ca es sv tw
        </IfModule>
        AddType application/x-tar .tgz
        AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php4 .php3 .phtml
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
        AddHandler send-as-is asis
        AddHandler imap-file map
        AddHandler type-map var
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
        MIMEMagicFile /etc/config/apache/magic
</IfModule>
<IfModule setenvif_module>
        BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        DeflateCompressionLevel 2
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.[0678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s7  !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
Include /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-ssl.conf
Include /etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts-user.conf
Include /etc/config/apache/extra/httpd-ssl-vhosts-user.conf

Include /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-msv2.conf
Include /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-musicstation.conf
Include /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-photo.conf
```

Include /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-video.conf

Comment: That ssl config file is *not* the one being used unless you've changed the URLs and removed the port.  Port 8081 is not the port one reaches by https://host/, port 443 is.  If you can't find a config file with 443 in it, then you may have something else entirely running there.  Try `netstat -nap` to see what is listening on port 443.

Answer (score 0):

Move the DocumentRoot "/share/Web" directive above the  section in your  /etc/config/apache/extra/apache-ssl.conf file.